# [cgal]; 3D Delaunay Triangulation

Tags: cgal

I'm trying to do a 3D Delaunay Triangulation and I need to obtain the circumcenters of this triangulation. I've done it this way:

```
  typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_3<K, Tds> Triangulation;

  // Construct the triangulation in parallel
  Triangulation T(V.begin(), V.end());
  assert(T.is_valid());


  centros.open("centros.txt");

  //With this I would obtain the circumcenters of the triangulation?:
  for (Triangulation::Finite_cells_iterator it = T.finite_cells_begin(); it != T.finite_cells_end(); it++)
  {
    cout << it->circumcenter() << " / " << T.dual(it) << endl;
  }
```

However, I obtain centers way too far from my initial points, so I'm doubting if this is the correct way of obtainint the circumcenters of the spheres. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the circumcenter is not necessarily inside the tetrahedron. This is especially true if you have some elements that are well shaped.

See the following 2D Delaunay Triangulation of 4 points and the corresponding circumcircles:
[image]

Comment: Sorry but with this answer I still don't know if the code is right. Shouldn't the code take into account all this? I've been looking for ways of obtaining the circumcenters for 3 weeks and I haven't found or understood anything which I can use properly :(

Comment: the circumcenter() function does return the circumcenter.

Comment: could you give me an example of how using this function?

Comment: You wrote some code using it, so I don't understand your question.

Comment: I don't think i'm obtaining properly the circumcenters because I obtain centers way TOO FAR from my initial points (vertex) and that's not possible, so there is something I must be doing wrong

Comment: Look at my picture. It features 4 points, and the Delaunay triangulation of those points. I also draw the circumcircles of those 2 triangles. As you can see they are FAR from the input points.

Comment: I will try to process the information you have given me. Thanks for the help.